# Jackson :loosing backslash from json string during deserialiastion

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, backslash

Unable to retain the backslash in the java object after deserialtion

I have below json
`{\"Num\":\"44566\677\"}`"

When I deserialise this to object

I am loosing the backslash

Expected :6787\32433
Actual:678732433

This is what I tried

```
String json = "{\"num\":\"6787\32432"}";


Objectmapper obj = new Objectmapper();


obj.enable(ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CAHATCTER);


obj.readvalue(json, new Typereferenxe<Map<String,String>>(){}));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: I am not familiar with Jackson, so just a hunch: It could be that the backslash is handled as an indicator for escaping the following character (similar to how you use \n to start a new line in a String). Have you tried using a double backslash \\? This would escape the second backslash and keep it in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash itself should be escaped so try to add another backslash into your Json - change `{\"Num\":\"44566\677\"}` to `{\"Num\":\"44566\\677\"}`

Also, if you are interested you can use a simple `JsonUtils` class for serializing and deserializing simple JSON to/from POJO. JsonUtils is a thin wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class. your code would become a one liner:

```
Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(json, Map.class);`
```

`JsonUtils` class comes with Open Source MjgntUtils java library written and maintained by me. Here is [JsonUtils Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). You can get the library as [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) - with source code and Javadoc